# Would ObjectionJS .query() get all the result before executing the where() / findById() function?

Tags: database, knex.js, objection.js

For ObjectionJS, as this line will fetch all the persons in db:

```
const people = await Person.query();
```

Would the query() in the line below fetch all the persons in db before executing the findById function?

```
const person = await Person.query().findById(1);
```

One thing I want to ensure is to fetch minimal data from database. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the [documentation](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#find-queries) the query in the `.findById` case is built before sending to database, so any chaining you do with `where` or anything else is set into the statement before executing:

- `SELECT * FROM persons;` first case
- `SELECT * FROM persons where id=1;` second case